# refetchOnFocus and isLoading / isFetching

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a client side react app, navigation is done using react router v 6.

In the root component (always mounted), I have a hook query with the flag `refetchOnFocus = true`

```
const { isLoading } = useMyQuery(undefined, { refetchOnFocus: true })

if (isLoading) return <Spinner />
```

the problem is that each time I focus the tab, `isLoading` is always true, is this the correct behavior?? I thought that `isLoading` only fires on first mount and then `isFetching` runs each time I focus the tab??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, in RTK Query, `isLoading` shows if a request is being loaded or not, only for that query, while `isFetching` reflects if any query is currently being requested. `isLoading` is specific to a query and `isFetching` is global to all active queries in RTK Query.